# How to make a new polygon/feature from a point which is NOT a centroid? ArcGIS

Tags: polygon, point, arcgis

I've spent all morning searching help sites and digging through the FAQs and worksheets but have failed miserably.

I am an ArcGIS novice so I hope this isnt too much of a "newbie" question but I'm trying to work out how to make a new polygon/feature from a point which is NOT a centroid?

```
----                ----
| . | <--not this   |   |
----       this-->  .---
```

I have a series of points where the Easting and Northing listed represents the lower left hand corner of a 200m square. I know how to make a circular buffer which I can convert to a square with the Feature Envelope to Polygon tool but this isnt really what I want.

The data is of 3g strengths which is meant to be in grid squares. I cannot upload this file this due to NDA.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually changed the eastings and northings tool to move 100m east and north accordingly. Then I used the buffer tool using the new point location as a centroid and turned that into a square.

Comment: Huh...yeah, I suppose that would work. BTW, this would have probably gotten a response in gis.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow itself is a bit light-on for GIS experts. I flagged it to be moved, but apparently it's easier just to close it. :/

Comment: Apologies. I'm new here, didn't realise there was a GIS specific area.