# grid of 10km * 10 km from centroids

Tags: gis, arcgis

I have a point layer which are the centroids of each cell of a grid. Each cells is of 10km per 10 km. How can I recreate this grid from the centroids and the cell size?

I have to say that I am a newbie in gis things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790351/how-to-make-a-new-polygon-feature-from-a-point-which-is-not-a-centroid-arcgis) - you're effectively asking for what Matthew didn't want, which is the simpler version. Make a circular buffer around each centroid, and convert that to a square with Feature Envelope to Polygon. (or possibly Minimum Bounding Geometry, depending on your licence level)

For the record, this kind of question is better suited to [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com), since it's not technically a programming question.